# Multiple Database updates in single application

Tags: c#, .net, database, automation, relational-database

I want to build a small .net application which can update multiple databases with same data.
This will be some sort of automated appication. I have some idea in mind but I am looking for some ideas from senior ppl before starting development on it. Please share your views.

Appreciate your help. Thanks !!

Comment: Will each database be comprised of the same technology e.g. All SQL-Server, MySQL Oracle? or do they have the potential to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the low level view, it should enumerate all target databases and save changes to them.

From the architectural perspective, you should think of proxy design pattern usage. Thus, you will use the abstraction `IDatabase` in your app, but will switch from proxy to the single database implementation at any time:

```
// database abstraction
interface IDatabase
{
    void SaveSomeData(IData data);
}

// example of implementation
class SQLDatabase : IDatabase
{
    public SQLDatabase(string connection)
    {...}

    abstract void SaveSomeData(IData data)
    {
        // establish db connection using given connection and run sql queries against it.
    }
}

// proxy which can save data to several databases.
class DatabaseSaver : IDataBase
{
    private IDatabase[] _databases;

    public DatabaseSaver(IDatabase[] databases)
    {
        _databases = databases;
    }

    void SaveSomeData(IData data)
    {
        foreach(var db in _databases)
            db.SaveSomeData(data);
        // TODO: error handling situations are omitted.
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Tengiz..i get the design that i need to follow..thanks for that but as you said from low level.. is code would be like database connection, running queries etc..can we have some reusability or any common guideline to follow

Comment: In general there can't be a lot of re-usability / common things, as different databases might even have different schemes for the same data. If you are creating databases just now, then you can have the common rules for them, by having exactly the same schemes, etc; but that is not required at all if you follow the pattern provided by me. Just make sure any uncommon scheme/database to have its own implementation (unlike SQLDatabase class which is very general in my example). There might be implementations like LocalSQLDatabase, RemoteOracleDatabase, MyAccessFileDatabase, etc. All's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DataSets

These can be serialized, and then applied to another database. Assuming that all target databases are in synch this should work without too many problems. You will have to refrain from using stored procedures and other 'interactive' database features though.

Essentially you will use the dataset in offline mode, and later apply the changes to 'a' database. Repeat that and you will update 'the' databases.

Note that you are most likely better served with some DB-level replication (Mysql, Postgresql, Oracle, SQLServer all support this in one way or another)

Comment: Thanks Sehe for answeres but do you mean to day create dataset and by using serialization (xml) convert it to different form and feed to another database. Actually all these database structure will be different also i could not understand line "Note that you are most likely better served with some DB-level replication (Mysql, Postgresql, Oracle, SQLServer all support this in one way or another)" Could you elaborate on that plz..